# Filtering on content type gives error No valid values found

Tags: php, drupal-8

I was creating a View and found this issue:

```
Filtering on content type gives error No valid values found
```

Even if adding content type in filter correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was:

While adding `Content Type` filter, I accidentally selected `All Displays` and as other blocks are also getting the same configuration, the View was throwing error.

**Solution:**

Gone to other View Displays and removed the Filter unnecessary for them.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with an exposed filter on a view that wouldn't allow me to save my changes with a similar error:
`"No valid values found on filter: Content: Has taxonomy terms (with depth)."`

The view master or "default" did not have the filter in question (so it wasn't just a case of removing it from the default or any other page, block, etc. in the view)

It turned out having the filter set to required was the caused it. Which seamed strange being I could select a term in the exposed filter list in the view display and it would filter perfectly as it should, but just wouldn't allow to save.

Being the filter was in reference to taxonomy vocabulary list of terms I did find you could select one of the terms to load automatically for the filter which would allow the view to be saved without the error notice - however this caused other unwanted side effects where in the view page (not the views page tab) the actual page the filter was on, loaded the filter by default to what was selected, when you changed it the view would then filter to what you selected BUT the initial state of the filter went back to default (which is undesired).

I then tried (back in the views filter criteria) to select all by default which it also accepted via view save - HOWEVER now it auto-selected one random term on initial load and did the same when you changed it (even tho the view filtered and updated with whatever you selected, the filter just returned to it's default selection) again undesired.

So again in the filter criteria for the filter in question I deselected all terms so nothing is set which makes it work correct (select a term in the list hit update and content filters and selection remains) but "still being required wouldn't let me save the view"

I finally just started trying a few things and poking around until I finally just un-checked required in the filter settings. No more error, and since there is no default selection the filter does what it states on initial load will select one at random which is fine 99% it will actually be set through the URL to the page but in the event the page wasn't loaded that way you can change the selection for the filter and click apply and the selection stays and page updates accordingly.

Long story short if all else fails and you had made it required just uncheck required for the filter settings.

Comment: This answer may be helpful but it is too verbose. Try to cut out unnecessary information and limit it to only the details of your solution and explanation of why they work or what you did.